# Autocompilation does not occur when a file is changed in a react project through a running docker compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose

I run my react project through docker compose, but files change during development, and the project does not compile on its own. You have to manually restart the container.
docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
  react:
    build: ./react
    volumes:
      - "./frontend_react:/code"
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:14-alpine

WORKDIR /code

RUN yarn install --frozen-lockfile

CMD npm start
```

.dockerignore:

```
Dockerfile
package-lock.json
node_modules
```

File tree:

```
docker-compose.yml
react/
  public/
  src/
  .dockerignore
  Dockerfile
  package.json
  yarn.lock
```

I tried adding the COPY string to the Dockerfile file and deleting it in docker-compose.yml string volumes